# ASP.NET MVC - putting controller & associated views in the same folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

We are currently using the default folder structure for our MVC app, and were wondering if it is possible to instead put a Controller and its related views into the same folder.

For example, a subset of our current structure is:

```
 Model folder
   OrderViewModel.cs
 Views folder
   OrderView.aspx
   OrderGrid.ascx
   OrderHeader.ascx
 Controllers folder
   OrderController.cs
```

Desired:

```
 Order folder
   OrderController.cs       
   OrderGrid.ascx
   OrderHeader.ascx
   OrderViewModel.cs
   OrderView.aspx
```

We have hundreds of actions/views, and they're currently grouped into too few controllers.  This is partly because it becomes a pain to navigate around the project when flipping back and forth between a view and its related classes.  The above solution would allow a developer focusing on one controller action to have all of them easily accessible.

I guess Areas could help with this too, but we'd have to make ~100 areas (one per set of closely related screens) to make this useful from my team's POV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default controller factory uses reflection to find all classes that derive from `Controller`, so no matter in which folder you put them, as long as they are public and derive from `Controller` it will work. But IMHO mixing views and controllers into the same folder is not a good idea. If it is a matter of organizing your controllers why not create subfolders in the `Controllers` folder?

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is that our developers get annoyed going back and forth between the Views folder and the Controllers folders (and other folders, such as ViewModels and Mappers, which I'm going to consolidate either way).  They want to have them in one place so they can switch between everything related to an action quickly.  They are coming from a webforms background, so I can understand to some degree.  They love ASP.NET MVC, but are annoyed by their perceived inability to find things immediately.

Comment: There is a shortcut to go between an Action Method and its view. This can make it easier to find stuff. If you right-click on a Action Method and select "Go to View". You can right-click from the view and select "Go To Controller" and it will take you to the default controller for that view. The keyboard shortcut ctrl & M then ctrl & G does the same.

Comment: Good tip, Richard - this will ease some of the pain (At least until I convince my boss to spend some money on a Resharper licence)

Comment: "But IMHO mixing views and controllers into the same folder is not a good idea." - why?

Comment: Re: "mixing view and controllers is not a good idea." Realize that there are two dimensions of the system at odds here, the architectural and the business. The original poster wants to keep all parts that deal with a certain business concern in one place. The default ASP.NET MVC layout spreads a single business concern out quite a bit so that architecturally-similar classes can stay together. Between these two choices I'd rather have things grouped by business concern than by architectural concern.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that diverging from convention is a good idea, as people are probably used to the standard folder layout - but I do feel your pain.

Navigation between files would be less painful if Visual Studio had some more of the features found in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html).

The fact is, pretty much any folder structure will degrade over time, as more files are added to the project, and better tools are usually a more efficient solution to the problem.

To be fair, it looks like VS2010 is starting to take some of the IntelliJ ideas on board, so things will probably improve - but there's a long way to go before Microsoft catch up.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that there is a [plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) that provides lots more functionality for Visual Studio - pretty much bringing it up to the same level as IntelliJ