# What is the opposite of domain driven design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm looking for a term that describes a design pattern (or anti-pattern) that describes when a system is organized by generalizations rather than the terms of the business.

For example consider the domain driven example of:

```
Customer.Load
Account.Load
Orders.Load
```

vs:

```
Load.LoadCustomers
Load.LoadAccounts
Load.LoadOrders
```

Another example could be seen here in mvc:
[ASP.NET MVC - putting controller & associated views in the same folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944972/852208)

While more about organization vs design, the comment from pettys IMO is correct:

> Realize that there are two dimensions of the system at odds here, the
>   architectural and the business. The original poster wants to keep all
>   parts that deal with a certain business concern in one place. The
>   default ASP.NET MVC layout spreads a single business concern out quite
>   a bit so that architecturally-similar classes can stay together.
>   Between these two choices I'd rather have things grouped by business
>   concern than by architectural concern

There is only one way to physically organize the project.  The OP is asking to organize by domain and pettys describes the default organization as "architecturally" organized.  But it is this "architectural" organization that I'm better trying to classify.

It seems to me that this is aspect-oriented *design*, ie design favoring a classification with respect to a general process instead of specific terms of the business.  I do not intend to confuse this with aspect-oriented programming which can be complementary to DDD, but it IS confusing which is why I'm wondering if there is a better name.

Comment: You could probably call that "service oriented architecture" (obviously with a negative connotation). Your second example emphasizes the WHAT, thereby ignoring the WHY side of things.

Comment: Operation Driven Design (ODD) ?

Comment: I have never heard of a name for this architecture. But it definitely seems to favor procedural programming instead of OOP. I believe I have seen a couple of similarly useful patterns in several blog posts claiming to be the holy grail of software engineering

Comment: @GhostCat - SOA and DDD can complement each other, ie the individual services can still follow a DDD organization.

Comment: @HoussamHamdan i can see that.

Comment: @djvuk - I think there is good reason for the current lack of a name - this aspect ONLY oriented design, I consider an anti-pattern.  It seems to arise when design is based on over-generalization.  But I was wondering if it did in fact have a name in order to more easily point out the trap a design might be falling into.

Comment: @b_levitt didnt get the message. Do u think the name has potentials or not ?

Comment: @dkvuk - i know it's been a long time, but note the answer I submitted below which I reference your comment.  I left out procedure driven design if you would like to post an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous generalizations around which a system can be organized. As far as I know, there were a few in vogue circa 2003 when DDD was published.

- Table-driven or data-driven design, which typically meant deriving your implementation from a specific set of relational data.
- Model-driven design, which typically meant deriving your implementation from UML diagrams.
- Configuration-driven design, which typically meant converting as much of your implementation as possible into XML files.

I'm sure there were more, and you could say that all of them focus more on the system's architecture than its domain. In retrospect you could consider some or all of them to be anti-patterns. In the words of Neal Ford,

> Today's best practice is tomorrow's anti-pattern.

reference: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/07/01/domain-driven-design.aspx

Comment: I do like the quote ;)

Comment: This prompted me to try to match up against known anti-patterns:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_design

This is sorta the "BaseBean" idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was prompted to go back and read this after somebody upvoted and realized there may be an answer here.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_design i half settled on BaseBean.  However, in the comments @djvuk mentions "proceedural programming".  I think he may have hit it - the anti-pattern here can be described as procedure or function driven - it the procedure or lifecycle the code is included in is the same, even though the domain in which it is applied is entirely different.  Models, Views, Controllers for example provide the same general function or procedure, even if they are created for entirely different domains.

Saying this now, it is clear, at least in the case of MVC, that the pattern is influencing or even leaking into the design, rather than the other way around.  The pattern is something for objects within DDD or feature-driven to follow, but it need not be part of the design.

I will submit two possible anti-pattern names here:

- Function Driven Design
- Pattern Driven Design